# Pass data from a Parent ViewController to Child VC without Storyboards - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, api, viewcontroller

I couldn't find a way to pass the data to the Child VC once i get the data through a UITextField from the Github API

```
protocol GithubManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateGithub(_ githubManager: GithubManager, github: GithubModel)
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}

struct GithubManager {
    let profileUrl = "https://api.github.com/users"
    let clientId = // deleted this
    let secretId = // deleted this

    var delegate: GithubManagerDelegate?

    func fetchProfile(profileName: String) {
        let urlString = "\(profileUrl)/\(profileName)?client_id=\(clientId)&client_secret=\(secretId)"

        performRequest(with: urlString)
    }


    func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }

                if let safeData = data {
                    if let github = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                        self.delegate?.didUpdateGithub(self, github: github)
                        print(github)
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }

    }

    func parseJSON(_ githubData: Data) -> GithubModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            let decodeData = try decoder.decode(GithubData.self, from: githubData)
            let name = decodeData.name ?? "The user does not have a name"
            let login = decodeData.login ?? "No username by this name." // TODO: Change to give a alert
            let avatarUrl = decodeData.avatar_url
            let blog = decodeData.blog ?? "No Blog"
            let bio = decodeData.bio ?? "No Bio"
            let location = decodeData.location ?? "No location"
            let followers = decodeData.followers
            let following = decodeData.following


            let github = GithubModel(githubName: login, githubUser: name, githubAvatar: avatarUrl, githubBio: bio, githubLocation: location, githubBlog: blog, githubFollowers: followers, githubFollowing: following)

            return github

        } catch {
            delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

In the Parent VC in the textFieldDidEndEditing I take the input text and use that to fetch the information from the GithubAPI

```
if let username = searchTextField.text {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.githubManager.fetchProfile(profileName: username)
            }
        }
```

Then in my Child VC I use the GithubManagerDelegate, where I use DispatchQueue where, to populate the labels with the information. But the information is empty, because I can't pass the to the child once the data is recieved.

```
func didUpdateGithub(_ githubManager: GithubManager, github: GithubModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.usernameLabel.text = github.githubName
        }
    }
```

The way I go from the ParentVC to ChildVC:

**navigationController?.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true)**

Hopefully I made myself clear what the problem is...

Comment: Create a variable name in profileVC, set it before you push the profileVC

Answer (score 1):

when you try to pass data between `parent` ViewController and `child` ViewController you should add child not navigation to the child.

in `child` ViewController : `var passingName: String?`

For Example

```
let child = #YourChildViewController insitiate it.
        self.addChild(child)
        child.passingName = passingName
        self.view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
```

I hope this solution helps you